# jQuery selecting a dropdowns by name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having a problem to select a dropdown with a variable as name:

```
var dropDownOption = 2;
$([name='dropdownName'] option:eq("+ dropDownOption +")).attr('selected', true);
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Missing quotes probably `$("...")`

Comment: could you also post the HTML you are using?

Comment: Yes, it is `$("[name='dropdownName'] option:eq("+dropDownOption+")").attr('selected', true);` right?

Comment: look at the color coding... your quotes are screwed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be this:

```
$("[name='dropdownName'] option:eq("+dropDownOption+")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

or:

```
$("[name='dropdownName'] option:eq("+dropDownOption+")").prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes.

```
$("[name='dropdownName'] option:eq("+ dropDownOption +")").attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotation marks around the string:

```
$("[name='dropdownName'] option:eq("+ dropDownOption +")").prop('selected', true);
```

You can also use the `eq` method:

```
$("[name='dropdownName'] option").eq(dropDownOption).prop('selected', true);
```

Unless you are using a multi-select, you can just set the selected index of the element:

```
$("[name='dropdownName']")[0].selectedIndex = dropDownOption;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are messed up, it should be:

```
$("[name='dropdownName'] option").eq(dropDownOption).attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the drop down is a variable the selector would be as in the following line:

```
$('selecct[name=' + dropdownName + ']').children('option').eq( dropDownOption )
.prop( 'selected', true );
```

If that was just shorthand then use:

```
$("select[name='dropdownName']").children('option').eq( dropDownOption )
.prop( 'selected', true );
```